# PyFMI parameter estimation and handling of fixed model parameters different from default

Tags: jmodelica, pyfmi

I have started to in PyFMI use parameter estimation with the procedure model.estimate() and works well.

From the documentation (Andersson et al 2016) as well as practical use I understand that model parameters are taken from the compiled FMU-model if not estimated. It would have been very practical to have an option to provide a dictionary with a set of the fixed parameter values different from the default of the model. Is there any way to provide that?

The current workflow is that for a larger model built up of parts from libraries, then you need to make a copy of these models and set parameters to the proper value in the code, and then compile it. It is a somewhat tedious procedure. Perhaps I have misunderstood something?

Andersson et al (2016): "PyFMI: A Python package for…”
https://portal.research.lu.se/portal/files/7201641/pyfmi_tech.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my contact Christian Winther at Modelon I learn that I understand the workflow right. He see also the advantage to have a possibility to have a list (or dictionary) of parameters that is changed from the default parameters and remain constant during parameter estimation. It may come in a future update.